# Text file to JSON in Java?

Tags: java, json, parsing, serialization, text

I have a text file like this **demo.txt**

```
name        : Cherry.API.DEV
version2    : Test
uuid        : 0492389a-43243-ewr234342-343d
xx          : {@{fdsfsdfsf}
lastSession : 0.0
activeOK    : True 
learn       : ok
```

I want to read demo.txt file and then convert as a JSON like this

```
{"name":"Cherry.API.CI", "variableName":{"module":"Cherry","ID" : "0492389a-43243-ewr234342-343d","systemdebug": "True"}}
```

Comment: share the code you tried so far.

Comment: I used split() function but this is getting confusing

Comment: i can give a hint, if you are using split function, split by colon, and trim from both side, you will get the values, put line by line inside the arraylist object or hashmap, and create json.

Answer (score -1):

In Groovy it could be:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def str = """name        : Cherry.API.DEV
version2    : Test
uuid        : 0492389a-43243-ewr234342-343d
xx          : {@{fdsfsdfsf}
lastSession : 0.0
activeOK    : True
learn       : ok
"""

def map = [:]
str.splitEachLine(~':', { List<String> list ->
    map.put(list[0].trim(), list[1].trim())
})

def json = JsonOutput.toJson(map)
println json

assert json == '{"name":"Cherry.API.DEV","version2":"Test","uuid":"0492389a-43243-ewr234342-343d","xx":"{@{fdsfsdfsf}","lastSession":"0.0","activeOK":"True","learn":"ok"}'
```

It prints:

```
{"name":"Cherry.API.DEV","version2":"Test","uuid":"0492389a-43243-ewr234342-343d","xx":"{@{fdsfsdfsf}","lastSession":"0.0","activeOK":"True","learn":"ok"}
```

The solution in Java with [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.txt")));
String line;
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] tokens = line.split(":");
    if (tokens != null && tokens.length > 1) {
        String key = tokens[0];
        String value = tokens[1];
        if (key != null && value != null) {
            map.put(key.trim(), value.trim());
        }
    }
}
String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println(json);
```